# SQL query - Filling column depending on

Tags: sql, pivot, crosstab

My DB reports several terminals with installed softwares (only specific software), row by row. Here's an example:

```
HOSTNAME | MAC ADDRESS | IP ADDRESS | SOFTWARE NAME
---------------------------------------------------
PC-AAA   | 94-da-r2-12 | xx.xx.xx.xx| TeamViewer
PC-AAA   | 94-da-r2-12 | xx.xx.xx.xx| Google Chrome
PC-BBB   | 94-da-s4-16 | xx.xx.xx.xx| TeamViewer
PC-BBB   | 94-da-s4-16 | xx.xx.xx.xx| Google Chrome 
etc.
```

How can I build my query in order to have a column for each software, as the following example?

```
HOSTNAME | MAC ADDRESS | IP ADDRESS | TeamViewer | Google Chrome
----------------------------------------------------------------
PC-AAA   | 94-da-r2-12 | xx.xx.xx.xx| TeamViewer | 
PC-AAA   | 94-da-r2-12 | xx.xx.xx.xx|            | Google Chrome
PC-BBB   | 94-da-s4-16 | xx.xx.xx.xx| TeamViewer |
PC-BBB   | 94-da-s4-16 | xx.xx.xx.xx|            | Google Chrome
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 0):

This is how to pivot an SQL query...
SQL server supports pivot, MySQL and others don't

If there is a fixed number of softwares, a `CASE WHEN` and `GROUP BY` will work

```
SELECT
HOSTNAME, MAC ADDRESS, IP_ADDRESS, 
CASE
WHEN (SOFTWARE_NAME = 'TeamViewer') THen 'TeamViewer'
ELSE ''
END AS TeamViewer
CASE
WHEN (SOFTWARE_NAME = 'GoogleChrome') THen 'GoogleChrome'
ELSE ''
END AS GoogleChrome

FROM
log_table
GROUP BY
HOSTNAME, MAC ADDRESS, IP_ADDRESS
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT HOSTNAME, MAC_ADDRESS, IP_ADDRESS,
       (CASE WHEN SOFTWARE_NAME = 'TeamViewer' THEN SOFTWARE_NAME END) as TeamViewer,
       (CASE WHEN SOFTWARE_NAME = 'GoogleChrome' THEN SOFTWARE_NAME END) as GoogleChrome
FROM log_table;
```

If you wanted one row per host and addresses, then use aggregation:

```
SELECT HOSTNAME, MAC_ADDRESS, IP_ADDRESS,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SOFTWARE_NAME = 'TeamViewer' THEN SOFTWARE_NAME END) as TeamViewer,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SOFTWARE_NAME = 'GoogleChrome' THEN SOFTWARE_NAME END) as GoogleChrome
FROM log_table
GROUP BY HOSTNAME, MAC_ADDRESS, IP_ADDRESS;
```

This is not the output you specify but it seems more useful.